# windows azure website preview dedicated IP for A record

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

So I have a reserved instance on windows azure websites preview.  I want to point my domain at it directly, not just the **www**.mydomain.com CNAME record which is mostly what i've seen people recommend.  I have the CNAME on the **www** working just fine.  But when you go to "mydomain.com" instead of "www.mydomain.com" it doesn't hit my azure website.

Is there any way to get the DNS "A" record to point at the azure website?  I cannot find anywhere that will give me an IP address to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It is now supported in Windows Azure. If you use a reserved instance, then it may be configured via the `Manage Domains` button on the bottom of the control panel.

Comment: It's a curious decision on their part to enable this for the new Websites concept but not for Cloud Services.

Comment: For cloud services there is no need for this, because the IP address will never change and in that case you have full rights to log in to the virtual machine via remote desktop any required settings.

Comment: The IP resets when you delete the production deployment which happens anytime endpoints change (a common case for us and a big problem if your DNS provider imposes short TTLs).

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, no, you can't get a static IP address for Windows Azure Web Sites, so you can't set up an A record. The standard practice is to have your apex domain (example.com) redirect to the www subdomain (www.example.com), where you already have a CNAME set up.

Comment: Not at this stage although I believe it is coming.

Comment: @smarx - how would one do that redirect? An HTTP redirect would require a webserver, so you'd need a separate server somewhere just to server those redirects. Is there some way to do a redirect in DNS?

Comment: It requires a webserver, but many (most?) registrars offer this service themselves. It's often called "domain forwarding." (That's what GoDaddy and 1&1 call it.) There's also http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect, with which I have no experience.